# Why is dimethylmercury so poisonous?

Tags: proteins

According to the Wikipedia article [Karen Wetterhahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Wetterhahn), Karen Wetterhahn died after only a very small amount of dimethylmercury got absorbed through the gloves. What is it about the way the body works that makes dimethylmercury so poisionous. I don't know very much about biology. I know a few things like how proteins act like a catalyst. I would like an answer that starts all over from scratch giving me the right basics after which I will understand the answer of why dimethylmercury is so poisonous and then explains why it's so poisonous.

Comment: I think this question needs some focus. Why do you ask an answer that starts from scratch?

Comment: @James Because I don't have all the information I need to understand an answer suited for experts in biology.

Comment: @Timothy "From scratch" is indicative that a question needs some more research. Asking about "why code X does Y from scratch" on SO would result in swift closure. It's hard to tell what you are actually asking.

Comment: For a very disturbing article on dimethyl-mercury and Karen Wetterhahn, see [The dangers of dimethylmercury](https://www.chemistryworld.com/opinion/the-dangers-of-dimethylmercury-/3010064.article), published in Chemistry World in 2019

Answer (score 2):

- Organic mercury compounds like Methylmercury or Dimethylmercury act as toxins by binding to thiol or sulfhydryl groups of
  proteins. These Mercury compounds cause [oxidative stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidative_stress), [lipid
  peroxidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_peroxidation), mitochondrial dysfunction, and changes in heme
  metabolism.
- Dimetylmercury is absorbed via gastrointestinal tract and later it
  enters bloodstream and is circulated to whole body. It binds
  with essential proteins like haemoglobin through the sulfhydryl groups present in
  [cysteine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cysteine). These complexes resemble the structure of [methionine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methionine), therefore it easily circulates throughout the body and could cross the blood-brain barrier.
- Mercury can bind to mitochondrial enzymes which can lead to cell
  injury and death. It is reported that mercury can inhibit [aquaporins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaporin)
  which prevents water transport across cell membrane.
- Mercury also inhibits the kinase activity of protein [LCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lck), which
  decreases the level of T-cells and weakens the immune system.
- Mercury also act as neurotoxin by inhibiting the neuronal membrane
  excitability by effecting postsynaptic activity. It  inhibits [Protein
  kinase C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_kinase_C) and [Alkaline phosphatase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_phosphatase), which damages brain formation and
  functioning even at blood-brain barrier.
- Organic mercury mainly causes developmental effects by binding with
  the [tubulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubulin)  protein,  which prevents microtubule assembly and
  inhibits the process of mitosis.
- Mercury also results in  autoimmune response by effecting Major
  histocompatibility complex (MHC) class II molecules, self peptides,
  T-cell receptors, or cell-surface adhesion molecules.

(Via:  http://www.t3db.ca/toxins/T3D0361

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/dimethylmercury )

Comment: Is it exactly the same reason why dimethylcadmium is also so very poisonous?

Comment: Yes..but it enters the body through inhalation.

Comment: Check out this link:  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.medicaldaily.com/most-dangerous-chemical-world-why-chemists-steer-clear-one-substance-394764%3famp=1

Comment: A good succinct answer to a vague question. +1